# How to set null values in result projection to zero with QueryDSL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, querydsl

I like to know how to set the null value in the projection pronostico2.nropack.sum()...

```
new HibernateSubQuery().from(pronostico)
                             .where(pronostico.aeropuerto.eq(vuelo.aeropuertoDestino)
                             .and(pronostico.fechareg.before(fechaHoraSimulacion)))
                             .unique(pronostico.nropack.sum()).loe(aeropuerto.cappack.subtract(vuelo.numpack))))
```

When the pronostico table is empty in DB, the value returned in pronostico.nropack.sum() is null, but i want to be zero. I tried with coalesce like this:
          pronostico.nropack.sum().coalesce(0)

.. but i get no answer. Instead of that, i get a Cast Exception: Cannot convert Long to Integer...

Someone has the answer?

PD: The complete query is:

```
    QVuelo vuelo = QVuelo.vuelo;
    QAvion avion = QAvion.avion;
    QTipoAvion tipoAvion = QTipoAvion.tipoAvion;
    QAeropuerto aeropuerto = QAeropuerto.aeropuerto;
    QPronostico pronostico = QPronostico.pronostico;
    QPronostico pronostico2 = new QPronostico("pronostico2");

    List<Vuelo> vuelos = consulta.from(vuelo)
                            .innerJoin(vuelo.avion, avion)
                            .innerJoin(avion.tipoAvion, tipoAvion)
                            .innerJoin(vuelo.aeropuertoDestino, aeropuerto)
                            .where(vuelo.aeropuertoOrigen.idaeropuerto.eq(idAeropuertoActual)
                                    .and(vuelo.salidaest.after(fechaHoraSimulacion))
                                    .and((vuelo.numpack.add(nroPaquetes).loe(tipoAvion.cappack)))
                                    .and(new HibernateSubQuery().from(pronostico)
                                            .where(pronostico.aeropuerto.eq(vuelo.aeropuertoDestino)
                                                    .and(pronostico.fechareg.before(fechaHoraSimulacion)))
                                            .unique(pronostico.nropack.sum()).loe(aeropuerto.cappack.subtract(vuelo.numpack))))
                            .list(vuelo);
```

Comment: Could you file a bug for this here https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues

Answer (score 3):

This may also be useful to someone. When you are performing a aggregate sum operation, you may want to treat null values as 0 instead. This is mainly useful if you want the correct sorting, nulls and 0 sort differently.

```
QMyEntity myEntity = QMyEntity.myEntity;

from(myEntity).list(new QMyProjectionClass(
  (NumberExpression<Double>) myEntity.minutes.coalesce(0d).asNumber().sum()
));
```

This results in the native SQL (Oracle in this case):

```
sum(nvl(myentity1_.minutes, 0))
```

The entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

  ...
  private Double minutes;

  public Double getMinutes() {
    return minutes;
  }

}
```

The projection class:

```
public class MyProjectionClass {

  private Double totalMinutes;

  @QueryProjection
  public MyProjectionClass(Double totalMinutes) {
    this.totalMinutes = totalMinutes;
  }
}
```

Note: running the maven-apt-plugin would generate the Querydsl metamodel classes QMyEntity and QMyprojectionClass.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
pronostico.nropack.sum().coalesce(BigDecimal.ZERO)